# Will my IP be used against me in this scenario?

Tags: privacy, ip

I went in a public chatroom. I had a bitter fight with someone. The person blackmailed me. I looked for privacy policy of the chatroom and it said they store my IP, which is visible to the chatroom owner.

My concerns are:

1. What all information can be extracted from my IP?
2. Do I need to worry about my breach of privacy?
3. What can a hacker do if they have my IP?
4. If I use by mobile hotspot for my laptop. Is my laptop also in danger along with my smartphone?

Comment: This is more of a legal question than a security question, although I don't expect it will be on-topic there either.  In general though your IP address won't do anyone any good without a court order, so unless you think you are going to get sued I wouldn't worry about it.  Since you were using your mobile phone as a hotspot, something as simple as switching your phone into and out of airplane mode, or restarting it, will likely be enough to get you a new IP address

Comment: @ConorMancone Ohk. Can it be used to know mylocation or which sites I visit or something like that?

Comment: Do not repost closed questions.

Comment: Your IP will give someone your general geographic area, depending on how your ISP assigns IPs (it could be the wrong geographic area). Someone would only know what sites you visit if they have access to those sites access logs.